# Mathematica Refuses to Output ContourIntegral and DoubleContourIntegral in Nice Mathematical Notation

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, front-end, symbols, operators

I experience a strange behaviour of handling the Contour and Double Contour Integral symbols \[ContourIntegral] and \[DoubleContourIntegral] in Mathematica. Whatever I try theyy behave differently than \[Integral].
Consider the following input

```
Integrate[f[x], x \[Element] V]
ContourIntegral[f[x], x \[Element] t]
DoubleContourIntegral[f[x], x \[Element] S]
```

The first statement outputs a nice mathematical notation using the \[Integral] Symbol (ignoring the obvious and clear error about the invalid integration variable). The other two, dont evaluate to any of the symbols. Even if I enter the above Contour Integrals with \[ContourIntegral] and \[DoubleContourIntegral] notation they evaluate to the ContourIntegral and DoubleContourIntegral forms. Trying TraditionalForm, HoldForm or Inactivate do not help either. Any Ideas how to convince Mathematica that the symbols stay in the original entry form?

Comment: @bbgodfrey It's a ``System` `` symbol with no defined meaning.  The input `\[ContourIntegral] f \[DifferentialD]x` is interpreted as `ContourIntegral[f, x]`, but it does not  typeset the output with the special integral symbols. @ Rainer, you can control the output formatting with `MakeBoxes[]` or `Format[]`.

Comment: @MichaelE2  Thanks.  I misinterpreted the question.